# Why is request dispatcher looking for view in spring mvc even when a request mapping is defined?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring mvc application, the configuration is given below. I have properly configured spring context, dispatcher servlet, and annotation processing. Still I have this problem where even when I define a request mapping, spring is trying to look for JSPs and I get following error

```
HTTP Status 404 - /resp/WEB-INF/views/public_html.jsp
```

However, I'm able to call the other request mappings (mostly POST) successfully. Please see the configuration information below. All suggestions are welcomed.

**web xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/springApplicationConfig-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>viewsLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/views/</param-value>
</context-param>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springApplicationConfig</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springApplicationConfig</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**springApplicationConfig-servlet.xml**

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.pkgName" />

<bean id="internalViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**/*" /> 
        <bean id="webContentInterceptor"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
            <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
            <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true" />
            <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true" />
            <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class LandingPageController {


@RequestMapping(value = "/" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView homePage(HttpServletRequest request) {

    return new ModelAndView("index", "model", null);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/public_html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView homePagePub(HttpServletRequest request) {

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
}}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use this xml property in your `internalViewResolver` Bean. <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />

Comment: @VigNesh tried adding the property. But same error as before.

Comment: Do you really have 'WEB-INF/views/public_html.jsp' ?

Comment: @pmverma No, there is no such JSP. However, I have such request mapping in one of my controllers ("/public_html"). Where I;m trying to redirect to index.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Let's revive this one... :)

That should have worked.... but anyway you have other options to try. 
You can return a `RedirectView` instead, or just a `String` `'redirect:/'`.

```java
//...
@RequestMapping(value = "/public_html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public View homePagePub() {
    return new RedirectView("/", true);
}
// - OR -
@RequestMapping(value = "/public_html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String homePagePub() {
    return "redirect:/";
}
//...
```